# Making Reusable Controls With JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, partial-views

It is easy enough to create a partial view, and just as easy to render said view. But what if I want said view to have associated JS local to it? And what if I want this view to be rendered multiple times per page?

Basically take something like a tabbed view of textareas that can be added and deleted dynamically. This is easy enough to make one of.

Now, putting that into a partial view and rendering it would be easy. But What if I wanted the page to hoist multiples of the above "partial view". (Even though its pretty frowned upon to have a partial view with javascript in it.)

Is this feasible in any way? Perhaps partial views are not exactly what I'm looking for?

I don't really have any code because this isn't so much a code related question, as it is an architecture(?)/theory question.

Answer (score 0):

If repeating the same partial view requires the same block of JavaScript to be repeated multiple times for multiple instances of the view on one page, that should indicate to you that you've got design problems going on in your JavaScript. That's code repetition that's begging to be refactored. Your script should be written such that it's designed to be loaded once and work - if you need to refer to the markup of the partial view, do so by using classes rather than IDs and so forth, such that your both your HTML and its associated scripts work as a repeatable module.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to disagree with sphanley. I like to see gadgets as whole objects, wholly functional by itself, so when you use it, you just drag it & drop, and it works without affecting other elements in the page. For that it needs to encapsulate everything it needs, JavaScript, CSS, HTML, etc.

However, instead of embedding JavaScript, it might just call a predefined function in a custom library specific to it, thus minimizing code when multiple gadgets are used in the page. And it will need to use ID selectors, not class or any other, so it does not affect other elements unintentionally.